# Sitecore, wrong type of inherited template field created by TDS

Tags: c#, sitecore, sitecore7.2, glass-mapper, tds

I have a problem with template inheritance:

I have base template (let say *Parent*) which contains the following field:

- Theme (Droplist with query specified)

And template (*Child*) derived from it.

The issue is that once I inherited *Parent*, and generated model for it with TDS, I got:

`public virtual string Theme  {get; set;}`

But expected to get *Guid* class. Once I swithced *Theme* field to type *Multilist* I got:

`public virtual IEnumerable<Guid> Themes  {get; set;}`

Which has *Guid* type in it...

How can I tell to TDS(GlassMapper) to have *Guid* instead of *string*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally, I found my mistake while writing this question... I used wrong type for *Theme*:

should use *Droplink* instead of *Droplist*.

Answer (score 2):

You've already figured out that you need to use a `DropLink` field type (which stores a guiGUID) instead of DropList (which just stores the value).

Instead of returning the GUID and then looking up the item again in Sitecore to then retrieve the values, you can have the TDS CodeGen templates return the linked item type instead by setting the object type in the `Custom Data` property field.

[image: TDS Codegen]

There are [2 main settings](https://github.com/HedgehogDevelopment/tds-codegen/blob/master/Sitecore.Master/Code%20Generation%20Templates/GlassV3Item.tt#L34) of interest:

- `type` : For single linked items, e.g. DropLink. Generated code will output:

  `public virtual AssetLibrary.LookupValue MyFieldName { get; set; }`
- `generic` : For multiple linked items, e.g. MultiList field

  `public virtual IEnumerable<AssetLibrary.LookupValue> MyFieldName { get; set; }`

Since most of the time you want a guid to resolve to a specific type, this saves some boilerplate code to lookup linked items and Glass will automatically resolve to the linked item.